# Possible calculation error using current divider rule on a non ideal current source circuit

Tags: current-measurement, current-source, error, current-divider

I am going through my notes in preparation to an exam, the following was taken straight from the board as my lecturer wrote it.

[image: Notes from whiteboard]

As far as im aware the current divider rule should be $$I1 = It * (Rt/R1)$$

However it is written here as $$I1 = It * (R2/Rt) $$

there must be something I am missing bit I cant figure it out.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

This was the formula that I thought was valid across the board : -

[image]

However Spehro Pefhany has shown this is not valid for all cases.

Comment: What is I1 and what is It - mind-reading is a different site.

Comment: Il put it this way - Current divider rule : $$In = It * (Rt/Rn)$$ however the formula shown has Rt as the denominator instead of numerator, and also uses the other resistor as numerator, not the one in question, im trying to find current through R1. take a look at that formula is it me or is that NOT the current divider formula to find current through R1 ?

Comment: I1 is current through resistor 1 , It is total current .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's identical to the current divider rule shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider):

[image]

Rt = 3K here (the resistor in parallel with the current source)
Rx = 6K
It = 9mA

So \$ I_X = I_T \cdot \frac{R_T}{R_X+R_T} = 9ma\cdot \frac{3K}{3K + 6K} = 3mA\$

Comment: Thank you, this has helped very much! I will show you the formula I was going by as an edit to my original question, so you dont think im a complete idiot. this has helped very much

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two 1 ohm resistors in parallel and the total current flow is 1A. This means \$I_T=1A\$ and \$R_T=0.5\Omega\$ therefore: -

\$I_{R1} = 1A\cdot 0.5\Omega\div 1\Omega\$ = 0.5 amps as expected.

The formula you believe to be incorrect does seem incorrect but, just a formula on its own and out of context could mean anything.

However, if you jiggled the algebra and said that: -

\$R_T=\dfrac{R_1 R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ (R1 and R2 in parallel)

And then divided it by R1 you'd get the same formula on your paper. I think your problem was that you were thinking the Rt was R1+R2 (maybe?).

Comment: This has certainly helped me understand, as you can imagine I thought the current divider formula that I have screenshotted was valid throughout, did not realise it had to be manipulated somewhat , I appreciate you answering my question